# Finding the parametric equations from a certain set of points (software)

Tags: calculus, parametric, math-software

I am a student in High school trying to do a math project which requires parametric curves. So, what I want to do is to draw curves (through plotting points or vector drawing) and find their parametric equations so I can use them for further calculation.

However, I cannot seem to find a software to help me. Does anyone know of any software or technique I can use to get parametric functions by drawing curves?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you give more details about your maths project? What you are trying to do most likely does not exist.

Comment: My project involves finding the optimal jungle path for the video game League of Legends. For this one of the parameters that I am going to measure is the distance between certain camps. However, the shortest distance between the different camps are curves due to walls. I wanted to model these curves so I can find their distance using the parametric curve distance method.

Comment: You would need to approximate this path using a series of straight line segments. Basically, plot some points a fixed distance apart for your route, and then add up the distance of these line segments.

Comment: Hmm, so there's no way to find the function of a curve? I guess I will use line segments to find the answer. Thanks for the help :D

Comment: Yes, in general you cannot find the function of a curve from the graph. This is because we only have names for functions that are useful to mathematics. There is always a finite distance that can be moved (left, right, up and down) in the game anyway.